# Resource in Designer ok, Runtime exception eresnotfound in module

Tags: delphi, components

I am trying to add a few images to my new component. So I did this

Project -> Resource and Images

Added a new Resource
 Filename : Logo.png
 Type : RCDATA
 Identifier : LOGO

On the Constructor I do this :

```
  OptionsImage.Glyph.LoadFromResource(HInstance,'Logo',RT_RCDATA);
  OptionsImage.Glyph.SourceHeight:=24;
  OptionsImage.Glyph.SourceWidth:=24;
```

In Designer this works flawlessly. But if I try to run this ... I get the
error :

Exception EResNotFound in module Project1.exe at 00074128.
Resource LOGO not found.

Why is it not finding the Logo at run time ?

Thank you for the kind help.

**UPDATE 1 :**

I have a GridButton.bpl in this I have on top

```
{$R *.res}
{$R *.dres}
```

With this alone , the Designer is working correctly, but If I try to run I get the error.

Now If I add to the Unit : cxGridButton.pas the same lines

```
{$R *.res}
{$R *.dres}
```

I recieve a Warning that I have duplicate resources . But now it works in Designtime and Runtime.

I must be doing something horribly wrong. But what ?

**UPDATE 2**

The other question is the same yes, but the answers are not working.

Meanwhile I solved it but I do not understand why is it working now.

GridButton.bpl

package GridButton;

```
{$R *.res}
{$IFDEF IMPLICITBUILDING This IFDEF should not be used by users}
{$ALIGN 8}
{$ASSERTIONS ON}
{$BOOLEVAL OFF}
{$DEBUGINFO OFF}
{$EXTENDEDSYNTAX ON}
{$IMPORTEDDATA ON}
{$IOCHECKS ON}
{$LOCALSYMBOLS OFF}
{$LONGSTRINGS ON}
{$OPENSTRINGS ON}
{$OPTIMIZATION ON}
{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}
{$RANGECHECKS OFF}
{$REFERENCEINFO OFF}
{$SAFEDIVIDE OFF}
{$STACKFRAMES OFF}
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
{$VARSTRINGCHECKS ON}
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
{$MINENUMSIZE 1}
{$IMAGEBASE $400000}
{$DEFINE RELEASE}
{$ENDIF IMPLICITBUILDING}
{$IMPLICITBUILD ON}

requires
 *******;

contains
  cxGridButton in 'cxGridButton.pas';

end.
```

And the Unit itself has

```
implementation

{$R GridButton.dres}
```

Now it works at Designtime and at Runtime . Is there a Bug in the Resource Manager or I did something wrong ? Can someone please explain.

Comment: I found that one, but I can't get it working. I did not want to spam that question

Comment: It looks like you are using some DevExpress components. In that case you should add the appropriate DevExpress packages to the requires clause of your package and remove the cxGridButton from contains.

Answer (score 1):

The resources added via *Project -> Resource and Images* are compiled into a separate resource file name *.dres*. This resource file has to be mentioned in the *DPR*. Usually the IDE takes care of adding this file, but that may somehow missing in your case.

Things are a bit more complicated when you compile outside the IDE - say on a build server. In that case you have to take care of creating the *DRES* file yourself.

Comment: please see my update. Thank you.